# Python plist parser IOError: [Errno 63] File name too long:

Tags: python, input, plist

my Python plist parser does not like my long string that is in plist format.

```
plist_data = plistlib.readPlist(plistString)
```

plistString is actually the contents of the file I opened. Oddly enough, putting the input file into the readPlist function works, but I had to do some further formatting of that file within python.

I run that above code and get an `IOError: [Errno 63]` on the console. Not sure how to avoid this? I am guessing the function is looking for "raw" input, instead of a String. How do I trick it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read a string as a file, use [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html).

```
fakeFile= StringIO.StringOI( plistString )
plist_data = plistlib.readPlist(fakeFile)
```

It's better not to open and read the pList file.  `plistlib.readPlist` does the opening and reading for you.

Comment: wow, I ended up doing the most convoluted solution. I made a tempfile, saved my string to it. opened that tempfile and read it in the plistlib

Comment: @RD. Wow that's bad.  Also. You should never have read the pListString in the first place.  Simply give the filename to `plistlib.readPlist()`.

Comment: The reason I did that is because readPlist had ignored (stripped) some characters in the string that I needed to use. I read the string in, converted the ignored special characters into \escape characters and read them back in.

Answer (score 2):

`plistlib.readPlist` takes file or file name, not contents. No surprise you get this error:

```
#define ENAMETOOLONG    63      /* File name too long */
```

Try `plistlib.readPlistFromBytes(data)` or use StringIO to present your string as a file

Comment: wow, I ended up doing the most convoluted solution. I made a tempfile, saved my string to it. opened that tempfile and read it in the plistlib

Comment: `plist_data = plistlib.readPlistFromBytes(plistReader)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'readPlistFromBytes'`

Comment: looks like readPlistFromBytes is only for python3. If you are still on 2.x, then StringIO is the way